# Express returns CORS error when AJAX call gets 404?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I have one express server making ajax calls to another and it works great unless the front-end server requests a bad route, then it is handled here after my routes:

```
app.use(function(req,res,err,next){
    console.log("404:"+req.route);
    res.status(404).send("bad route");
    end();
});
```

When i send the bad route in firefox I see the network error: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" but then after that I see: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/bad This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

but all other calls work correctly, and i can see the client getting the 404 request. For this test I'm taking a working call and changing part of the URL.

The back end Express shows: "404:undefined". I can't find anything on the internet that addresses this. I'm very confused.

For clarity I'm seeing the CORS headers in the app and it's working for all other calls. Other than this express has been really fun to use, hopefully someone can see the flaw in what I'm doing.

As requested, here is how I set my cors:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');


    next();
});
```

Comment: How you set CORS, and how you handle other routes, any one route if you can share

Comment: I included this information. Thanks.